# run another while read after first one finished

Tags: bash

I want to run another `while read` with different input file + python script after first one is finished.
Example code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line;
do
    python3 script.py -d $line --output test
done < domain.txt && 
mv *.txt savehere && 
dos2unix savehere/* && 
sort savehere/*.txt | uniq > done.txt
```

I know I could do:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line;
do
    python3 script.py -d $line --output test && 
    python3 script1337.py -d $line
done < domain.txt && 
mv *.txt savehere && 
dos2unix savehere/* && 
sort savehere/*.txt | uniq > done.txt
```

But this is not what I want - I need to use different input file and want to run `script1337.py` after `script.py` is finished going through `domain.txt` (it does not work with `&&` because it accepts 1 argument).

Comment: You question is not clear. You show what you *could* do and then say you don't want to do that: *what do you want to do*?

Comment: Umm, you want to run another while loop? I suppose you don't mean to just well, have another one, like `while read line; do this; done < file; while read line; do that; done anotherfile`. But if not that, then, what?

Comment: as I said, I want to wait for the script.py to finish going through domain.txt and then run script1337.py - the example was that I cannot use that as solution (because script.py is accepting one argument at time - which means that its gonna go right to script1337.py after it goes through first line in domain.txt) @glennjackman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's also a `while`-free way:

```
xargs -L 1 -I '{}' python3 script.py -d \"'{}'\" --output test < domain.txt &&
xargs -L 1 -I '{}' python3 script1337.py -d \"'{}'\"           < scriptfile.txt &&
mv *.txt savehere && 
dos2unix savehere/* && 
sort savehere/*.txt | uniq > done.txt
```

It'd be *less* efficient though, since it calls the `xargs` external util.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```bsh
while read -r line; do 
    python3 script.py -d "$line" --output test
done < domain.txt \
  && mv *.txt savehere \
  && dos2unix savehere/* \
  && sort savehere/*.txt | uniq > done.txt
```

Do you want this, using grouping braces?

```bsh
{
    while read -r line; do 
        python3 script.py -d "$line" --output test
    done < domain.txt
    while read -r line; do 
        python3 scripy1337.py -d "$line"
    done < other_input_file
} && mv *.txt savehere \
  && dos2unix savehere/* \
  && sort savehere/*.txt | uniq > done.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! however script1337.py is being completly skipped

Comment: I assume you noticed the filename `other_input_file` and replaced it with your actual filename, and you didn't just blindly cut and paste...

Comment: of course, everything is replaced correctly - if i change positions script1337.py with script.py then script.py is ignored and script1337.py executed

Comment: What is the exit status of `script.py`? Do you use `set -e` or `set -o errexit`?

Comment: those scripts are not made by me, however I can see that they both use sys.exit()

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/env python3
while read -r line; do  #foobar
    python3 script.py -d $line --output test #foobar
done < domain.txt && 
while read -r line; do  #foobar
    python3 script1337.py -d $line #foobar
done < scriptfile.txt && 
mv *.txt savehere && 
dos2unix savehere/* && 
sort savehere/*.txt | uniq > done.txt #foobar
```